# What kind of lightbulb is this and how do I change it?

Tags: lighting

[image: Bulb in eyeball mount]

I think it is a halogen, but I have no idea what kind of light bulb it is. It has a yellow warm light. How do I change it?

Can I use [this Halogen bulb removal tool](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Halogen-Bulb-Removal-Tool-Green/dp/B0027J282A/) to change it?

[image: Photo of bulb removal tool]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had very similar lights.
It looks a bit like this once unmounted:

[image: Unmounted light]

So basicly you just have to pull the outer circle down. It's held by two springs, so it should resist a little, but not too much.
Once you've taken it out, you will see what kind of light bulb it is.

Comment: I think the type is called 'GU10@

Comment: @Stese The type on the picture I posted is GU10, yes. But on the picture from the question, it could be something else, like the popular MR16. You can't say without seeing the back of the bulb.

Answer (score 1):

It's a twist base elevator light. With the same kind of base as an 1156 automotive bulb.   You push in firmly, twist to the left, and it should spring out.